# Using Unicode character &#10 between to Values in Ms Access report

Tags: ms-access

Please help me separating the 2 values which the other one be forced to go to next line. I have troubles in the Highlighted unicodes below:

Format([NETPREM],"Standard") **"&#10&#10"** Format([DST],"Standard")

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the HTML entities in the string, you need to end each with a semicolon, and you need the `&` operator to concatenate the strings:

```
Format([NETPREM],"Standard") & "&#10;&#10;" & Format([DST],"Standard")
```

If you want to put the LF (line feed) character in the string, use the `vbLf` constant:

```
Format([NETPREM],"Standard") & vbLf & vbLf & Format([DST],"Standard")
```

Or use the `Chr` function:

```
Format([NETPREM],"Standard") & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Format([DST],"Standard")
```